# can we have more generic type to shorten this code in F#?

Tags: f#, inline, primitive

I came across this code while reading "Programming F# 3.0":

```
type BitCounter =

    static member CountBits (x : int16) =
        let mutable x' = x
        let mutable numBits = 0
        for i = 0 to 15 do
            numBits <- numBits + int (x' &&& 1s)
        x' <- x' >>> 1
        numBits

    static member CountBits (x : int) =
        let mutable x' = x
        let mutable numBits = 0
        for i = 0 to 31 do
            numBits <- numBits + int (x' &&& 1)
        x' <- x' >>> 1
        numBits

    static member CountBits (x : int64) =
        let mutable x' = x
        let mutable numBits = 0
        for i = 0 to 63 do
            numBits <- numBits + int (x' &&& 1L)
        x' <- x' >>> 1
        numBits
```

I attempted to shorten this part by making an auxiliary function:

```
type BitCounter =

    static member CountBitsWithRangedMask x upBound typeConverter =
        seq { for i = 0 to upBound do yield 1 <<< i }
            |> Seq.map typeConverter
            |> Seq.map ((&&&) x)
            |> Seq.filter ((<>) (typeConverter 0))
            |> Seq.length

    static member CountBits (x : int16) =
        BitCounter.CountBitsWithRangedMask x 15 int16

    static member CountBits (x : int) =
        BitCounter.CountBitsWithRangedMask x 31 int

    static member CountBits (x : int64) =
        BitCounter.CountBitsWithRangedMask x 63 int64
```

But `static member CountBits (x : int)` caused a compilation error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int16
but here has type
    int
```

So I'm wondering if I can add some constraint like `Integral a` in Haskell on `CountBitsWithRangedMask`'s first argument.
Or is there any other solution that can simplify the original code?

Comment: I suspect replacing 0 with `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` everywhere will fix this but don't have time to check right now.  Might also need  to replace 1 with `LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne`

Comment: @JohnPalmer Indeed - both are necessary. @Javran Read about `inline` methods, especially with integral types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `LanguagPrimitives.GenericOne` and `LanguagPrimitives.GenericZero` combined with `inline` to acheive this.

```
let inline CountBitsWithRangedMask x upBound =
    seq { for i = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero to upBound do yield LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne <<< i }
    |> Seq.map ((&&&) x)
    |> Seq.filter ((<>) (LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero))
    |> Seq.length

let test16 (x:System.Int16) = CountBitsWithRangedMask x 15
let test32 (x:System.Int32) = CountBitsWithRangedMask x 31
let test64 (x:System.Int64) = CountBitsWithRangedMask x 63
```

Using this we also don't need the `typeConverter` parameter as the compiler does everything automatically.

This is a reasonably general method for these sorts of problems.

Comment: +1 I'd replace `i = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero` with `i = 0` and  `upBound` with `(sizeof<'a> * 8) - 1` to make `CountBitsWithRangedMask` even more generic. This way, `i` would be `int32`, but I guess it's rather save to assume that primitive integral types have no more than 2^32 digits.